# Match filename and file extension from single Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm sure this must be easy enough, but I'm struggling...

```
var regexFileName = /[^\\]*$/; // match filename
var regexFileExtension = /(\w+)$/; // match file extension

function displayUpload() {
    var path = $el.val(); //This is a file input
    var filename = path.match(regexFileName); // returns  file name
    var extension = filename[0].match(regexFileExtension); // returns extension

    console.log("The filename is " + filename[0]);
    console.log("The extension is " + extension[0]);
}
```

The function above works fine, but I'm sure it must be possible to achieve with a single regex, by referencing different parts of the array returned with the .match() method. I've tried combining these regex but without success.

Also, I'm not using a string to test it on in the example, as console.log() escapes the backslashes in a filepath and it was starting to confuse me :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that all files do have an extension, you could use

```
var regexAll = /[^\\]*\.(\w+)$/;
```

Then you can do

```
var total = path.match(regexAll);
var filename = total[0];
var extension = total[1];
```

Comment: I'm more of a .net regex guy but aren't you missing the first capture group?

Comment: @rtpHarry: The entire match (group 0) is the filename (including the extension), the first capture group (group 1) is the extension.

Comment: He needs file's name, not the whole path.

Comment: @Ademiban: I don't think so. He wants the same results as the code he has now, but do everything in a single regex.

Answer (score 10):

`/^.*\/(.*)\.?(.*)$/g` after this first group is your file name and second group is extention.

```
var myString = "filePath/long/path/myfile.even.with.dotes.TXT";
var myRegexp = /^.*\/(.*)\.(.*)$/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // myfile.even.with.dotes
alert(match[2]);  // TXT
```

This works even if your filename contains more then one dotes or doesn't contain dots at all (has no extention).
**EDIT:**
This is for linux, for windows use this `/^.*\\(.*)\.?(.*)$/g` (in linux directory separator is `/` in windows is `\` )

Comment: This fails with `'/tmp/myFile.txt'`

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but here's another solution that can handle multiple dots in the name and also when there's no extension at all (or an extension of just '.'):
`/^(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$/`

Taking it a piece at a time:
`^`
Anchor to the start of the string (to avoid partial matches)

`(.*?)`
Match any character `.`, 0 or more times `*`, lazily `?` (don't just grab them all if the later optional extension can match), and put them in the first capture group `(` `)`.

`(\.`
Start a 2nd capture group for the extension using `(`. This group starts with the literal `.` character (which we escape with `\` so that `.` isn't interpreted as "match any character").

`[^.]*`
Define a character set `[]`. Match characters *not* in the set by specifying this is an inverted character set `^`.  Match 0 or more non-`.` chars to get the rest of the file extension `*`.  We specify it this way so that it doesn't match early on filenames like `foo.bar.baz`, incorrectly giving an extension with more than one dot in it of `.bar.baz` instead of just `.baz`.
`.` doesn't need escaped inside `[]`, since everything (except`^`) is a literal in a character set.

`)?`
End the 2nd capture group `)` and indicate that the whole group is optional `?`, since it may not have an extension.

`$`
Anchor to the end of the string (again, to avoid partial matches)

If you're using ES6 you can even use destructing to grab the results in 1 line:
`[,filename, extension] = /^(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$/.exec('foo.bar.baz');`

which gives the filename as `'foo.bar'` and the extension as `'.baz'`.
`'foo'` gives `'foo' and ''`
`'foo.'` gives `'foo'` and `'.'`
`'.js'` gives `''` and `'.js'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use groups in your regular expression for this:

```
var regex = /^([^\\]*)\.(\w+)$/;
var matches = filename.match(regex);

if (matches) {
    var filename = matches[1];
    var extension = matches[2];
}
```

Comment: I'm more of a .net regex guy but aren't you missing the first capture group?

Comment: You're right. I just tested it, documentation was a bit confusing about it :P

Comment: Your code was correct before and is now broken. Where is `matches[2]` supposed to come from if you only have one capturing group?

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the first capturing group. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

This will recognize even `/home/someUser/.aaa/.bb.c`:

```
function splitPathFileExtension(path){
    var parsed = path.match(/^(.*\/)(.*)\.(.*)$/);
    return [parsed[1], parsed[2], parsed[3]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better approach as matches only valid directory, file names and extension. and also groups the path, filename and file extension. And also works with empty paths only filename.

```
^([\w\/]*?)([\w\.]*)\.(\w)$
```

Test cases

```
the/p0090Aath/fav.min.icon.png
the/p0090Aath/fav.min.icon.html
the/p009_0Aath/fav.m45in.icon.css
fav.m45in.icon.css
favicon.ico
```

Output

```
[the/p0090Aath/][fav.min.icon][png]
[the/p0090Aath/][fav.min.icon][html]
[the/p009_0Aath/][fav.m45in.icon][css]
[][fav.m45in.icon][css]
[][favicon][ico]
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?!\w+).(\w+)(\s)`

Find one or more word (s) `\w+`, negate `(?! )` so that the word (s) are not shown on the result, specify the delimiter `.`, find the first word `(\w+)` and ignore the words that are after a possible blank space `(\s)`