# Javascript regex match filename with extension

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello i need to match filnames with extensions.

Problem is that paths could be both unix and windows, so seperated by / or \ also unix allows . in filenames, so t.est.txt also should be matched.

My code :

```
var regex = new RegExp('[\\/]?([/\w+.]+/\w+)/\s*$');
var value = this.attachment.fileInput.dom.value;
console.log(value.match(regex));
console.log(regex.exec(value));
```

this regex works fine in [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/fAPpsL3Fg8). But for some reason ie, chrome and firefox does not match any string and returns null.

Comment: Please give an example what should **not** match.

Comment: You may find it easier when you can view your regular expression as a diagram: http://tinyurl.com/p5fp9ct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match filename and file extension from single Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001557/match-filename-and-file-extension-from-single-regex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just grab whatever's at the end following the last `\` or `/`, such as:

```
var file = str.match(/[^\\/]+$/)[0];
```

(Remember files don't always need extensions)

Though if you really want to force extension matching:

```
var file = str.match(/[^\\/]+\.[^\\/]+$/)[0];
```

Comment: In my case it always has extensions. Thanks, second one works perfect

Answer (score 6):

Try the following syntax:

```
var filename = (value.match(/[^\\/]+\.[^\\/]+$/) || []).pop();
```

It should work fine for the following examples:

```
"path/to/file.ext"     --> "file.ext"
"path\\to\\file.ext"   --> "file.ext"
"path/to/file.ext.txt" --> "file.ext.txt"
"path/to/file"         --> ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Credits go to [RegeBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)'s library for this snippet:

```
if (/[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$/im.test(js)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Good! Windows says \/:*?"<>| can not be filled in a file name.