# active navbar in bootstrap stay active on click of page title

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap nav bar and wondering why i cant get the menu page selected to stay  'high lighted ='lit' when the href title is clicked. My first problem was that 'home' was always 'lit'.the script below fixes that. I have 2 empty titles at moment and when they are clicked they stay 'lit' (they are dead pages with no href yet) . I ve tried over 10 js scripts and the best i can find is one below which allows the titles to be 'lit' on hover but they don't stay 'lit' on click. Except the 2 empty titles as mentioned above.

is it a CDN issue or is it abvious from my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active'); 
});
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">Listalot</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li ><a href="table1.php">My Sellers</a></li>
          <li><a href="applicant_card.php">New Customer</a></li>





           <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">

          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Figures <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

              <li><a href="figures2017.php">2017</a></li>
              <li><a href="figures2016.php">2016</a></li>
              <li><a href="figures2015.php">2015</a></li>
              <li><a href="figures2014.php">2014</a></li>
              <li><a href="figures2013.php">2013</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Compare Years</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>


 <li><a href="#">Mortgages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News Page</a></li>


         <!-- <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
           <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>   

        </form>   -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">



          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <li><a href="index.php">Log In</a></li>


  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
           <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>   

        </form>

  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>

  <div><br></div>
  <br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the window.location property and if it fits the link required set the active class.

Your code should do the trick always if the `location.pathname` value is the same value as the `href` property in the `a` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href$="' + location.pathname.match(/[^\\/]+$/)[0] + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active'); 
});
```

Maybe checking only for the end of the pathname (table1.php,applicant_card.php)  will work. The href attribute value ends with the last part of the `location.pathname` after the last `/`slash (from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292598/4635829 by [SmokeyPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763371/smokeyphp)).

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: i understand selctors just about...  what would this look like in code? thx

Comment: it worked!!   , great. I will go back and learn how you actually did it now . thx

Comment: it is now 2021 and i have no idea what i was asking... scary

Comment: I know that feel bro  