# How do I delete everything in a string till a curtain character in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, replace

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a lot of rows, around 300. Every row contains an single image URL, for example:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/images/products/onkruid.png` or
`http://www.mywebsite.com/images/services/remover/remover_start.jpg`

I want to delete everything in the URL till the last "/". So everything besides the file name and the file extension needs to be removed. I tried to doing it with replace() but the problem is that the path changes every time. I'm still quite new to JavaScript/Google Apps Script and I can't think of another way how I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get file name like below:

```js
const url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/images/products/onkruid.png';
const fileName = url.split('/').pop();
console.log(fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) in a browser  - if the URL API is not supported by your script then you need to use a regex. There a [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filename+regex+site:stackoverflow.com), for example

[Javascript regex match filename with extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292210/javascript-regex-match-filename-with-extension)

To keep the last `/` , add +1 to `lastIndexOf("/")` in the first function

Assuming you have a fully qualified URL with a filename at the end

```js
const getUrlWithoutFile = str => {
  const url = new URL(str);
  const path = url.pathname;
  return `${url.protocol}//${url.host}${path.slice(0,path.lastIndexOf("/"))}`
};  

const getFilename = str => {
  const url = new URL(str);
  const path = url.pathname;
  return path.slice(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
};  


console.log(getUrlWithoutFile("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/products/onkruid.png"))
console.log(getFilename("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/products/onkruid.png"))

console.log(getUrlWithoutFile("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/services/remover/remover_start.jpg"))
console.log(getFilename("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/services/remover/remover_start.jpg"))
```

Comment: To other readers: note that `URL` object from Web APIs is not available in GAS, it is a server-side language. On the other hand, if you are using a sidebar, one can get the values by invoking a function server-side with `google.script.run`, return them to the client and make advantage of all the Web APIs, including the one in the answer