# How can split filename and Extension using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I want to remove some charters and extension from particular filename and want only middle part
For example I have fiLename as **AA_BB_CC_20-300.tsv** and want that filename printed as **CC_20-300**

Can some please suggest me the regex pattern for it.

I have filename as

**AA_BB_CC_20-300.tsv**

and want that filename printed as
**CC_20-300**

Comment: do all files follow the same format (does it always start with AA_BB or 5 chars? do you need regex?)? please make an attempt, and share it

Comment: Do you *have* to use a regular expression?  `name.lastIndexOf('.')` is better than using a regular expression.  And how, exactly, do you determine what to remove from the front of the filename?  Is it always `AA_BB_`?  Is it always the characters up to the second underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the java regex to tackle this one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filename = "AA_BB_CC_20-300.tsv";
    String patternString = "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+_[^_]+)\\..*$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String desiredPart = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(desiredPart); // Output: CC_20-300
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions won't help you to split your filename. Seems you just all the characters starting from the 6th. You can do that with:

```
String firstPart = filename.substring(7);
```

Then you can remove the last four with:

```
String finalName = firstPart.substring(0,firstPart.length-4);
```

Comment: want extension removed aswell

Answer (score 0):

More generic regex solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211246/11938328

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "AA_BB_20-300.tsv";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)(\\.[^.]*)?$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("filename: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```